# Indoor drone with an automatic docking/charging procedure

Tags: automation, drone

I want a good indoor drone that also has a docking station at which it gets charged.

Ideally it would have this part automated with sensors so you could tell it to land when it's hovering over the docking station and it would land and begin charging.

Drone definitely needs to have a camera as well - higher the quality the better.

Essentially I'm looking for a nearly hands-free drone possibly for remote usage.

Comment: I have not found a drone that is commercially available (yet) that does this. However, there are [research](http://engineering.nyu.edu/mechatronics/projects/ME7836/Spring2015/Propeller_mini_project/AR-Drone/Mini_Project_2_2.pdf) projects that have accomplished this using an AR Drone ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vG_UZaogTGA), another - non AR Drone - docking on a "moving" target [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRjJV_WLluA)

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly a drone but more or less accomplishes most of the same thing. This thing is pretty awesome:

[image]
[image]

Site: http://global.varram.com/

---

Update: This product has horrendous support and the software is severely lacking with no plans of improvement for necessary things like LAN discovery.

Comment: Bad enough to make you want to delete your answer? Or could one live with it, given no alternatives?